# Using for loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, plot, matlab-figure

I have the following code :

```
t_p = 0.5
M_p=0.1;    
w = pi/t_p;
o_m = (-w*log(M_p))/pi;
k1 = 5*(o_m^2+w^2);
k2 = 10*o_m-1;
A = [0 1; 0 -1/5];
B = [0; 1/5];
C = [1 0];
K = [k1 k2];
kref = -inv(C*inv(A-B*K)*B);
Acl = A-B*K;
Bcl = B*kref;
Ccl = [1 0];
s=eig(Acl);
[ymatlab,tmatlab] = step(ss(Acl,Bcl,Ccl,0));
subplot(1,2,1)
plot(tmatlab(M_p),ymatlab(M_p),'bo-','linewidth',1)
```

Is there any way to write a loop which plots the tmatlab and ymatlab for values M_p = 0.1:0.1:0.3 so that it plots tmatlab and ymatlab for each M_p value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i=0;
for M_p=0.1:0.1:0.3;
    i=i+1;
    w = pi/M_p;
    o_m = (-w*log(M_p))/pi;
    k1 = 5*(o_m^2+w^2);
    k2 = 10*o_m-1;
    A = [0 1; 0 -1/5];
    B = [0; 1/5];
    C = [1 0];
    K = [k1 k2];
    kref = -inv(C*inv(A-B*K)*B);
    Acl = A-B*K;
    Bcl = B*kref;
    Ccl = [1 0];
    s=eig(Acl);
    [ymatlab,tmatlab] = step(ss(Acl,Bcl,Ccl,0));
    val{i} = char(strcat('M_p = ',num2str(M_p)));
    plot(tmatlab,ymatlab,'-','linewidth',1,'Color',[0,i*0.3,1-i*0.3])
    hold on
end
legend(val{1},val{2},val{3})
```

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Comment: Is there a way to make each plot (on the same axes use different marker and color styles) ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the accepted answer, if you don't desire a separate figure per plot, you can plot all of the graphs on the same figure with varying colours and varying marker styles.  Simply define a string that defines all of the possible colours you want with all of the possible marker styles you want.

After, simply spawn a new `figure`, use `hold on` and use a loop to plot each line with a different colour and different marker by accessing each of the strings defined previously.  In the example below, I define a three character string of `rgb`, symbolizing that the first plot is red, second plot green and third plot blue.  Each of the corresponding markers are `o`, `.` and `x`.  Therefore:

```
t_p = 0.5;
figure; hold on;
colors = 'rgb';
markers = 'o.x';
val = cell(1,3);
idx = 1;
for M_p=0.1:0.1:0.3;    
    w = pi/t_p;
    o_m = (-w*log(M_p))/pi;
    k1 = 5*(o_m^2+w^2);
    k2 = 10*o_m-1;
    A = [0 1; 0 -1/5];
    B = [0; 1/5];
    C = [1 0];
    K = [k1 k2];
    kref = -inv(C*inv(A-B*K)*B);
    Acl = A-B*K;
    Bcl = B*kref;
    Ccl = [1 0];
    s=eig(Acl);
    [ymatlab,tmatlab] = step(ss(Acl,Bcl,Ccl,0));
    %// Change
    plot(tmatlab(M_p),ymatlab(M_p),[colors(idx) markers(idx)],'linewidth',1);
    val{idx} = char(strcat('M_p = ',num2str(M_p)));
    idx = idx + 1;
end

legend(val{:});
```